# object.onfocusout deprecated or do i do something wrong?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to bind an `event` onto an `object`. However, it didn't work.

I though i maybe wrote the code wrong. So i searched for it, however they all wrote it exacly the same as i did. So i created a fiddle and tryed it out there. In the fiddle it don't work either.

```js
// This does not work
document.getElementById("test").onfocusout = function() {firstFunction()};

function firstFunction() {
    console.log("Im feeling sick");
}

// This one does work
document.getElementById("test2").addEventListener("focusout", secondFunction);

function secondFunction() {
    console.log("Im working fine!");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test">
<input type="text" id="test2">
```

So, is `object.onfocusout` depecrated or do i do something wrong here? I can't find anything regarding it being depecrated.

**The code:**

```
// This does not work
document.getElementById("test").onfocusout = function() {firstFunction()};

// This works fine
document.getElementById("test2").addEventListener("focusout", secondFunction);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is object.onfocusout depecrated or do i do something wrong here?

It isn't deprecated because it was never standard in the first place.

Use `addEventListener` instead.

Comment: That explains why i coudn't find anything about it, thanks!